# Terraform asking for "ami" and "instance_type" after importing current state

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an EC2 instance which is manually created on aws. I need to run a bash script inside my instance using terraform without recreating the EC2 instance.this is my tf file for this .

**instance.tf**

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykey" {
  key_name   = "mykey"
  public_key = file(var.PUBLIC_KEY)
}
resource "aws_instance" "example" {

key_name      = aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name
 provisioner "file" {
   source="script.sh"
   destination="/tmp/script.sh"
}
 connection {
    type ="ssh"
    user ="ubuntu"
    private_key=file(var.PRIVATE_KEY)
    host        = coalesce(self.public_ip, self.private_ip)
 }
}
```

**vars.tf**

```
   variable "INSTANCE_USERNAME" {
      default = "ubuntu"
    }
    variable "PUBLIC_KEY" {
      default = "mykey.pub"
    }
    variable "PRIVATE_KEY" {
      default ="mykey"
    }
    variable "AMIS" {}
    variable "INSTANCE_TYPE" {}
```

**provider.tf**

```
provider  "aws"  {
   access_key = "sd**********"
   secret_key = "kubsd**********"
   region = "us-east-2"
}
```

I have  imported my current state using

```
terraform import aws_instance.example instance-id
```

This is my state file

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.12.17",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "54385313-09b6-bc71-7c9c-a3d82d1f7d2f",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "aws_instance",
      "name": "example",
      "provider": "provider.aws",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 1,
          "attributes": {
            "ami": "ami-0d5d9d301c853a04a",
            "arn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:148602461879:instance/i-054caec795bbbdf2d",
            "associate_public_ip_address": true,
            "availability_zone": "us-east-2c",
            "cpu_core_count": 1,
            "cpu_threads_per_core": 1,
            "credit_specification": [
              {
                "cpu_credits": "standard"
              }
            ],
continues...
```

But when i run `terraform plan` it is showing error like

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on instance.tf line 5, in resource "aws_instance" "example":
   5: resource "aws_instance" "example" {

The argument "ami" is required, but no definition was found.


Error: Missing required argument

  on instance.tf line 5, in resource "aws_instance" "example":
   5: resource "aws_instance" "example" {

The argument "instance_type" is required, but no definition was found.
```

I couldn't understand why it is asking for instance_type and ami . Its is present inside the terraform.tf state after importing my state . Do i need to pass this data manually ? Is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: Importing just adds things to the state. You still need to define the resource to match it so that Terraform can do a diff check to see if the resource needs modifying to match the Terraform code. This requires you to at least set all the required fields for the resource, `ami` and `instance_type` being the 2 required parameters for the `aws_instance` resource.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR ,So Do i need to find my ami and instance_type and specify it inside my resource manually??

Comment: You can set any dummy value and then see what the diff shows. Or you can look at the state that you have imported and then set that and see that the diff should be empty.

Comment: HI @ydaetskcoR  i have tried to grep the ami and instance_type and exported values as TF_VAR_AMIS and TF_VAR_INSTANCE and passed this values to resource . but if i delete the terraform.tfstate and then again try to import the state it will show missing arguments error . is there any other way to call values from tfstates and pass to resources ?

Answer (score 2):

The `terraform import` command exists to allow you to bypass the usual requirement that Terraform must be the one to create a remote object representing each resource in your configuration. You should think of it only as a way to tell Terraform that your `resource "aws_instance" "example"` block is connected to the remote object `instance-id` (using the placeholder you showed in your example). You still need to tell Terraform the *desired configuration* for that object, because part of Terraform's role is to notice when your configuration disagrees with the remote objects (via the state) and make a plan to correct it.

Your situation here is a good example of why Terraform doesn't just automatically write out the configuration for you in `terraform import`: you seem to want to set these arguments from input variables, but Terraform has no way to know that unless you write that out in the configuration:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # I'm not sure how you wanted to map the list of images to one
  # here, so I'm just using the first element for example.
  ami           = var.AMIS[0] 
  instance_type = var.INSTANCE_TYPE
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name
}
```

By writing that out explicitly, Terraform can see where the values for those arguments are supposed to come from. (Note that idiomatic Terraform style is for variables to have lower-case names like `instance_type`, not uppercase names like `INSTANCE_TYPE`.)

There is no way to use existing values from the state to populate the configuration because that is the reverse direction of Terraform's flow: creating a Terraform plan compares the configuration to the state and detects when the configuration is different, and then generates actions that will make the remote objects match the configuration. Using the values in the state to populate the configuration would defeat the object, because Terraform would never be able to detect any differences.

Comment: Hi @Martin Atkins,Can we use terraform to execute a script or command on the remote infra which was  created  without using terraform ?